# Malos etiquetados dudosos

Tags: discusión, característica-nueva

Para los programadores que llevamos años al pie del cañon de `C++` nos resulta muy molesto el tener que andar aclarando que `C` y `C++` no es lo mismo. De hecho es bastante enervante el recordar que [No existe un lenguaje llamado `C/C++`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312326/there-is-no-language-c-c).

Cuando una pregunta es etiquetada como `C` y `C++` uno no sabe qué responder, pues responder en un lenguaje u otro es muy diferente ya que pese a que `C` es el predecesor de `C++`, éste último utiliza funciones diferentes, cabeceras diferentes, y en muchos casos aproximaciones muy distintas al mismo problema... además de que no comparten todas las palabras clave y algunas palabras clave compartidas tienen comportamientos diferentes en cada lenguaje...

... en resumen, una respuesta puede (y suele) ser **muy diferente** según se plantee en `C` o en `C++`, sin embargo varios usuarios [etiquetan con ambos lenguajes sus preguntas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/21925/como-puedo-obtener-la-longitud-del-contenido-de-un-hanlde), seguramente por creer que `C/C++` es un lenguaje o que `C` y `C++` son lo mismo.

En el meta de SOen sugieren [emitir un aviso cuando ambas etiquetas se usan simultáneamente](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252433/499359) y creo que podría ser una buena idea, no sólo con `C` y `C++` si no con otra pareja comunmente confundida como `Java` y `JavaScript`.

---

¿Podría tomarse alguna medida para intentar evitar usar etiquetas inadecuadamente emparejadas?

Comment: Más allá de que todos podamos estar de acuerdo (y de que algunos puedan argumentar que hay casos válidos con ambas etiquetas), el hecho de que muestres un *feature-request* del 2011 al cual no se le dio respuesta no es menor... Hay cosas que simplemente no son prioridad.

Comment: Si bien es cierto que hay casos válidos con ambas etiquetas, aún no he encontrado ninguno en SOes, dado que puede ser válido sugiero un aviso no una prohibición. Por otro lado, tan sólo estoy pidiendo opinión (`discusión`) y proponiendo una mejora (`feature-request`), se que no es prioritario pero por lo menos ya está dicho y queda registrado para su estudio.

Comment: [Aquí](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/20915/mostrar-el-numero-de-indice-de-un-vector/20966#20966) un ejemplo de una pregunta doblemente etiquetada, que recibe respuesta tanto para `C++` como para `C`; siendo ambas respuestas válidas y muy diferentes entre si por las diferencias entre ambos lenguajes.

Comment: Quizás no fui claro: me encantaría verlo implementado (y dudo seriamente que se haga). Por cierto, irónicamente, `discusión` y `característica-nueva` no deberían usarse juntas. :-)

Comment: @Mariano si, no sabía lo de esta otra pareja, pero me di cuenta luego que en [estos comentarios](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252430/499359) mencionan ese mal emparejamiento. Ahora no se si editarlo...

Comment: Por mientras, lo único que se puede hacer es dejar un comentario solicitando qué etiqueta debería quedar y/o editando la publicación para remover la etiqueta que genera confusión.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza eso no siempre es posible, en algunas ocasiones no se sabe qué etiqueta quería el usuario: [1](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/21925/como-puedo-obtener-la-longitud-del-contenido-de-un-hanlde), [2](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/21693/errores-al-usar-librerias-estaticas-en-qt), [3](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/20915/mostrar-el-numero-de-indice-de-un-vector), [`...`](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b%20c)

Comment: Para ello se ponen comentarios preguntando. En el peor de los casos donde no hay interacción del usuario, convendría cerrar la pregunta porque no está claro lo que se pregunta.

Comment: Depende de la pregunta, puede que ambas etiquetas fuesen válidas, ¿no? Puedo estar desarrollando un programa en C++, pero la parte del código en la que tengo un problema no requerir nada específico de C++, con lo que me valdrían soluciones que serían válidas tanto en C como en C++.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro es cierto que *algunas* preguntas pueden ser etiquetadas como C y C++ correctamente de manera simultánea; mas son pocas. En general no he visto ninguna en SOes que merezca ese doble etiquetado.